# setObject:forKey: method of NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is the first parameter supposed to be an object? A tutorial I'm following has the first parameter being textFieldBeingEdited.text, where it is defined in the .h file as

```
UITextField *textFieldBeingEdited
```

Isn't textFieldBeingEdited an object, and text is a property of that object?

The following code crashes:

```
[tempValues setObject:textFieldBeingEdited forKey:tagAsNum];
```

If I change it to the following then it doesn't crash:

```
[tempValues setObject:textFieldBeingEdited.text forKey:tagAsNum];
```

That doesn't make sense though since the first argument is supposed to be an object, and not a property.

Comment: BTW, as you are referring to UITextField I'm guessing you are talking about iOS development which does not use Cocoa it uses Cocoa Touch (tagged here as Cocoa-Touch) they are very similar but have differences, if you use the correct tags you stand a better chance of getting an answer since the right people will notice the question (i.e. some people knows lots about iOS development and have related tags under interested but don't care about Mac OS X dev. and have those tags ignored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A property is syntactic sugar for a getter method that returns an object and optionally a setter method that takes an object. The `text` property of the `UITextField` object provides a getter method that returns an `NSString` object that can be stored in an `NSDictionary`.

Essentially, a property provides two methods. For example, the methods implemented/synthesised by the `text` property may look like this (simplified for the sake of the example):

```
- (NSString *) text
{
    return text;
}

- (void) setText:(NSString *) newText
{
    if (text != newText)
    {
        [text release];
        text = [newText copy];
    }
}
```

When you use `object.text = @"Hello"`, it will actually send the `setText:` message with `@"Hello"` as the argument, and when you use `NSString *value = object.text;` it will actually send the `text` message, which returns an `NSString` object.

Comment: So all properties are objects?

Comment: No, some properties may be `int`, or other types that are not objects.

Answer (score 2):

`textFieldBeingEdited.text` is a property of UITextField, but it is also an object, of type `NSString`.